# crear y asignar una lista a LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html5, local-storage

Estoy trabajando con este [ejemplo](http://www.falconmasters.com/javascript/app-lista-tareas-javascript/) el cual es una aplicación en JavaScript que crea tareas en forma de listas.

Dentro de la funcion agreagar Tarea , quiero implementar localstorage. pero no consigo que funcione, creo la variable llamada checklist y una lista vacia.

despues de crear el elemento lista, hago un bucle para insertar en mi lista vacia los elemento que boy añadiendo  `div id="tareas"`luego quiero imprimir la lista `checklist`. Pero no lo consigo.

imprimo checklist

este es mi codigo.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  //Asignación variables
  var lista = document.getElementById("lista"),
    tarea = document.getElementById("tarea"), //input
    agregar = document.getElementById("agregar"); //button

  if (!localStorage.getItem('checklist'))
           localStorage.setItem('checklist', "");
  var checklist = []
  //  Funciones
  var agregarTarea = function() {
    var tarea = document.getElementById("tarea").value,
      nuevaTarea = document.createElement("li"),
      enlace = document.createElement("a"),
      hr = document.createElement("hr"),
      contenido = document.createTextNode(tarea); // crea un elemento con tarea como texto

    enlace.appendChild(contenido); //agregar el valor del input a enlace
    enlace.setAttribute("href", "#"); //añadimos la propiedad a enlace.
    enlace.style.color = "black";
    nuevaTarea.appendChild(enlace);
    lista.appendChild(nuevaTarea); //por ultimo, agregamos nueva Tarea (valor del input) a lista (contenedor)
    lista.appendChild(hr);
    document.querySelector('#tarea').value = '';

     for (var i = 0; i < lista.children.length; i++) {
            checklist.innerHTML = lista.children[i]
          }
     
        console.log(checklist);
  };


  //Eventos
  agregar.addEventListener("click", agregarTarea);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Checklist con javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container bg-danger py-3">
      <h1 class="text-center text-capitalize text-white font-weight-bold"> lista de tareas con javascript</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <form action="#" class="">
          <div class="form-group mt-5">
            <input type="text" id="tarea" class="form-control text-center py-2" placeholder="Agrega una tarea a la lista." autofocus autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="agregar" class="btn btn-outline-warning  btn-block btn-lg">Agregar Tarea</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--separacion -->
    <hr class="font-weight-bold bg-warning">
    <!--endbeparacion -->

    <!--lista-->
    <div class="container" id="tareas">
      <div class="title bg-warning my-5 py-3">
        <h2 class="text-center text-danger">Tareas a Realizar</h2>
      </div>
      <ol id="lista" class="text-center text-capitalize ">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, fugit.</a></li>
        <hr class="font-weight-bold mb-3">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, fugit.</a></li>
        <hr class="font-weight-bold mb-3">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, adipisci!</a></li>
        <hr class="font-weight-bold mb-3">
      </ol>

    </div>
    <!--endlista-->
  </div>
  <script src="js\checklist.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Agradesco que me ayuden o me digan como puedo asignar los elementos que se crean a la lista y almacenarlo a la variable `localstorage('checklist')`.
Gracias

Comment: En que parte de tu codigo estas agregando items a checklist?

Comment: En agregarTarea( ) creo la variable localstorage, luego de crear el elemento y añadirlo a la sección de tareas,  recorro las listas que se crearon y se las asignó a checklist[]. Al imprimir por consola me arroja " Checklist not defined".

Comment: Pero en el for no estas agregando nada al checklist, estas solo asignando el valor de lista.children y pisandolo con el ultimo valor

Comment: Es lo que te digo.. Al hacer eso no estas agregando nada a tu arreglo, por eso no te imprime nada

Comment: Cambien `checklist.innerHTML = lista.children[i]` a  `checklist = lista.children[i].
Ya imprime por consola lo que estoy insertando.  Gracias @Paulño Urbano
Ahora intente almacenas checklist dentro de `localStorage.setItem("checklist", checklist[i]);` aumente checlist++ pero ahora me imprime NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando como base el ejemplo para poder almacenar todo en **localStorage** es necesario que cada que se ingrese una tarea almacenar el texto en un arreglo y a su vez almacenar el arreglo como un JSON dentro de una variable **localStorage**.

El ejemplo no lo pongo para ejecución debido a que **SO** **localStorage** debido a que es un **sandbox**.

El **HTML** queda con el listado vacío y el formulario tal cual:

```
<div class="principal">
    <div class="wrap">
        <form class="formulario" action="">
            <input type="text" id="tareaInput" placeholder="Agrega tu tarea">
            <input type="button" class="boton" id="btn-agregar" value="Agregar Tarea">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tareas">
    <div class="wrap">
        <ul class="lista" id="lista">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

El JavaScript queda de la siguiente manera (Tiene comentarios explicando paso a paso):

```
var guardado;
(function () {
    // Variables
    let lista         = document.getElementById("lista");
    let tareaInput    = document.getElementById("tareaInput");
    let btnNuevaTarea = document.getElementById("btn-agregar");
    // Recibimos lo que tenemos guardado el LocalStorage
    guardado          = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('datos'));

    // Verificamos si guardado es diferente de null entonces
    // realizamos un ciclo for para agregar las tareas
    if (guardado != null) {
        for (i in guardado) {
            agregarTarea(guardado[i]);
        }
    }
    // En caso de que sea null la declaramos como un arreglo
    else {
        guardado = [];
    }

    // La funcion recibe el texto
    function agregarTarea(tarea)
    {
        let nuevaTarea = document.createElement("li");
        let enlace     = document.createElement("a");
        let contenido  = document.createTextNode(tarea);

        // Agregamos el contenido al enlace
        enlace.appendChild(contenido);
        // Le establecemos un atributo href
        enlace.setAttribute("href", "#");
        // Le agregamos el evento onclick haciendo referencia a la funcion
        // eliminarTarea mandando como parametro el evento
        enlace.setAttribute("onclick", "eliminarTarea(this)");
        // Agrergamos el enlace (a) a la nueva tarea (li)
        nuevaTarea.appendChild(enlace);
        // Agregamos la nueva tarea a la lista
        lista.appendChild(nuevaTarea);
    };

    // Agregar Tarea
    btnNuevaTarea.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // Verificamos que la tarea a ingresar no sea vacia
        if (tareaInput.value != '') {
            agregarTarea(tareaInput.value);
            guardado.push(tareaInput.value);
            localStorage.setItem('datos', JSON.stringify(guardado));
            tareaInput.value = "";
        }
        // Si es vacía le agregamos el placeholder de invalida
        else {
            tareaInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Agrega una tarea valida");
            tareaInput.className = "error";
        }
    });
}());

// Recibe como parámetro el evento
function eliminarTarea(link)
{
    // Verificamos el parentNode sea diferente de null
    if (link.parentNode !== null) {
        // Eliminamos la tarea clickeada
        link.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(link.parentNode);
    }
    // Verificamos si el texto existe en el arreglo general
    let index = guardado.indexOf(link.text);
    // Si existe lo eliminamos
    if (index !== -1) guardado.splice(index, 1);
    // Guardamos el arreglo en localstorage
    localStorage.setItem('datos', JSON.stringify(guardado));
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcional en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/eduardev/pen/wvKgbPd).

Comment: Gracias por responder, estoy entrando apenas en el mundo de JavaScript y este ejemplo me va de maravilla al hacer uso de JSON para almacernar objetos como listas.